# Jquery Ajax data prints HTML code

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I have below function to assign data for my HTML text fields.

Alert by the data is like `10,12, <!DOCTYPE HTML` further HTML code. I want to remove this HTML code please help me.

My code;

```
    function load1(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url:'<?php echo site_url('home/settings_screen); ?>',
        data:{test:'1'},
        success: function(data){
                window.alert(data); 
                var split_value = data.split(",");
                $("#older").val(split_value[0]);
                $("#younger").val(split_value[1]);

        });
    }
```

Comment: provide the home/settings_screen code

Comment: use some kind of seperator like `#&&#` and then split the code, grab the first part and youre done

Comment: @ImmortalDude I split it and took the data .but, I want to check if no data passing to here. At that time output only contain html code. So I can't check it is null.

Comment: why does it contain html?

Comment: on your server side if your returning anything empty means . return anything like this (0,0) so that here we can judge value is empty or not using if(split_value[0] !=0){ $("#older").val(split_value[0]); } like this

Comment: then where from your getting html code ???

Comment: @JYoThI no it is a controller.

Comment: did you loading any view in that controller ?

Comment: yes header and footer

Comment: Please provide `home/settings_screen`'s code. If you're going to return JSON, don't forget to `json_encode`. Otherwise, you will get HTML responded by the server. If you did `json_encode`, then you should provide the HTML code in order to make sure that's not error message.

Comment: Additionally, single-quote shouldn't be appeared in other single-quote sets. Change whoever of them into double-quote different from others.